# Order of destructors

Tags: c++, destructor, object-lifetime

I have these kind of classes:

Game:

```
class Game {
private:
    BoardField*** m_board_fields;
public:
    Game() { 
        m_board_fields = new BoardField**[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             m_board_fields[i] = new BoardField*[8]; 
        }
    }

    Game::~Game() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < 8; j++) {
                delete m_board_fields[i][j];
            }

            delete[] m_board_fields[i];
        }

        delete[] m_board_fields;
    }
}
```

BoardField:

```
class BoardField {
private:
    ChessPiece* m_piece;
    ....
public:
    BoardField::~BoardField() {
        delete m_piece;
    }
}
```

And on the close of the program I get error in ***~BordField***:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   this was 0xFDFDFDFD.

Did I made my destructors incorrect? What is the best way to clear memory from multidimensional array ?

Comment: It's a bad sign when just a few lines into a class definition there's indication of [three star programming](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. 1) For example: If `m_piece` was never initialized - it contains indeterminate value, and if you try dereferencing it (e.g. via the use of `delete`), your program exhibits undefined behavior. 2) We can see that you create an 2D array `m_board_fields`, which stores pointers to `BoardField`. Where are the contents of such array initialized? Since destructor tries to delete those, and, once again, dereferencing uninitialized pointers is undefined behavior.

Comment: Where is `new BoardField()` ?

Comment: @考えネロク in other functions

Comment: I have coded C and C++ since 1992, but I never use three star pointers. The syntax is just too horrible and error prone.

Comment: @StoryTeller the class definition is much larger, just didn't want to put everything here

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::array<BoardField, 8 * 8>` with some helper functions implementing indexing instead of performing large amount of heap allocations?

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor implemented? An assignment operator?

Comment: Why not `BoardField m_board_fields[8][8]`?

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array`. You are deleting but not allocating `m_board_fields[i][j]`. Also pay attention to things like `for (int j = 0; i < 8; j++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is are two fundamental flaws in your design:

- there is no clear ownership of the `BoardField`s:  someone create it, someone else deletes it.  It can work if you're very cautious but it's error prone.
- you do not ensure the [rule of 3 (or better 5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)):  if you have any piece of code where you create a copy of either your `Game` or a of any  `BoardField` the first object that gets destroyed will delete the `m_piece` pointer, and when the second object gets destroyed, it'll try to delete  a second time the same pointer, which is UB.

There is a third important issue:  you're over-using raw pointers:

- if m_board_fields is a 2d array of fixed size, make it a fixed size array (aka `BoardField* m_board_fields[8][8]`). If you want to keep its size dynamic, use vectors.
- a cell of m_board_field could be a pointer if there's some polymorphism expected.  But this seems not the case here, as obviously ChessPiece is the polymorphic class.  So better use plain fields instead of pointers (aka `BoardField m_board_fields[8][8]`).
- Finally, instead of using raw pointer to `ChessPiece`, better use a `shared_ptr<ChessPiece>` : you don't have to worry about shallow pointer copies and double delete;  the `shared_ptr` will take care of itself and destroy the object if it's no longer used.